# C pointer conversion rules

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef union stateof stateof;
union stateof 
{
  stateof* foo;
  double* bar;
};

typedef struct hunch hunch;
struct hunch{
  double* first;
  double* second;
};

void main(){
  #define write(x) printf("%d \n",x);

  int* storage = 0;
  stateof* un = (stateof*)&storage;
  un->foo = 300;
  write(storage);

  un->bar = 600;
  write(storage);

  hunch* h = (hunch*)&storage;
  h->first = 1200;
  write(storage);

  h->second = 1600;
  write(storage);
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
300   
600   
1200   
1200
```

What is happening here?

What does it mean for the `un->{foo,bar}` and `h->{first,second}` statements to execute when they most definitely do not point to valid structures? What is exactly occurring during this period and why is the output of the union different than that of the structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll describe all in details.

`int* storage = 0;` - creates a Pointer on the stack with zero value (points to NULL in other words).

`stateof* un = (stateof*)&storage;` - `un` points to the location of `storage` which is a pointer. So `un` points to the `storage`'s value which is now equals 0.

`un->foo = 300;` - assigns 300 into `storage` (lets think about `storage` like about some `int` value because it doesn't matter that it is a pointer in fact here), so `storage == 300` now.

`un->bar = 600;` - the same as the previous, because `un` is a union and all its fields in fact just different names for only one field (well, its `union`'s definition).

`h->first = 1200;` and `h->second = 1600;` are like the previous cases with only one exception that here values are assigned to DIFFERENT fields in the struct (different places in memory).

`write(storage);` - printing the value of `storage` (which is a pointer) but not the value where `storage` points to (`*storage`).

And of course, the last but not the least: NEVER CODE LIKE THAT ANYMORE! :)

Comment: @xappymah, the fact that `storage` is a pointer is important at least in that it means the first three modifications are likely to work (since they're also all to pointer types that share memory with `storage`).  If it were just `int` there would be even more room for error in the OP's program.

Comment: @Carl Norum, if you look here: `stateof* un = (stateof*)&storage` you'll find that here is used not `storage` but `&storage` which in fact is a pointer into the stack where `storage` resides. So there is no difference at all what value is on the stack either a pointer or an int value, because `un` will point to the same place.

Comment: @xappymah - exactly.  A pointer's worth of space *actually allocated* on the stack.  If `storage` were an `int`, only an `int`'s worth of space would be allocated.  There's no reason an `int` and a pointer have to take up the same amount of space - the fact that the OP did use a pointer may very well matter if a pointer and an `int` aren't the same size.  Since he writes to that allocated memory as a pointer every time, it can definitely make a difference.  Either way, the write through `h->second` is likely to be completely unallocated memory, and remains pretty dangerous.

Comment: @Carl Norum, oh, if you meant the size, then you are right. I just wanted to emphasize that it doesn't matter where `storage` points to because OP works with `storage`'s value itself. But of course the size of the allocated space on stack does matter. However, IMHO making `storage` an int value will not make the original code more or less error prone than it is now, because it is Really unsafe already:)

Comment: I just posted a comment on Carl Norum's answer, and I'll just clarify it even more here. Dereference un and you get storage's value. Storage's value can then be set by doing something heinous like *((int **) un) = 888. But apparently this is "similar" to doing just (*un).foo = 888. Why is this?

Comment: The answer in Carl Norum's answer (sorry for the pun :)).

Answer (score 7):

Your program causes *all kinds* of undefined behaviour.  You could get any kind of output imaginable.  Your compiler is probably giving you all kinds of warnings when you compile this code - try fixing those up and you should be headed in a better direction.

Assuming you have a normal sort of system, the reason you're getting the output you see can be explained:

1. modifying `un->foo` overwrites `storage` with the value `300` - then you print it out.
2. modifying `un->bar` overwrites `storage` with the value `600` - then you print it out.
3. modifying `h->first` overwrites `storage` with the value `1200` - then you print it out.
4. modifying `h->second` (DANGEROUSLY) overwrites some memory with the value `1600`, then you print out `storage` again - it's still `1200`.

Comment: So in this example given the assumption I'm running on a normal system, how is it that un->foo translates into the value of storage? The same thing with h->first. Basically what I'm asking is how does the compiler actually translate h->first into storage's value?

Comment: Well, the answer is simple. Any struct is represented in memory as sequence of its fields. So, pointer to the struct is also the pointer to the first field of the struct. The same resides to unions with respect to the fact that union contains only one field with several names.

Comment: Thanks, I suspected something like that was going on :)

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what will happen. The language standard doesn't say.

When you write a program, there is an implied contract between you and the compiler. If you write a correct program, it has to produce an executable that does exactly what the source code said.

When you use code like

```
stateof* un = (stateof*)&storage;
```

you are telling the compiler "I know for sure that `&storage` actually points to a stateof union. Trust me, I know what I am doing!".

And the compiler thinks "If you say so...", and acts accordingly. But as you have then broken the contract, it is free to do just about anything. We just don't know what the output could be, or if there would even be one.